# Delete buttons previously added

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I add 24 buttons using a Class at the start of my app and the user can press any or all of them. Then 'another' button has been pressed I would like to remove all of these 24 buttons.

Adding them:

```
for j in 0...2 {
    for i in 0...7 {
        // use the CLASS KSPIckButton to format the buttons
        let buttonOne: UIButton = KSPickButton(frame: CGRect(x: (j + 1) * 28 + (j * 80), y: (i + ii) * 35 + buttonSet, width: 110, height: 30))
            
        // Add the button to the storyboard
        self.view.addSubview(buttonOne)
        
    }
}
```

How can I delete them?

I would like to just have a simple loop through all 24 buttons using
self.view.Remove()
but cannot work out how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Add a tag

```
self.buttonOne.tag = 333
self.view.addSubview(buttonOne)
```

Then

```
self.view.subviews.forEach { 
   if $0.tag == 333 {  
      $0.removeFromSuperview() 
   } 
}
```

**Solution 2**

You can also add them to an array and loop over them with calling `removeFromSuperview`

**Solution 3**

```
self.view.subviews.forEach { 
   if $0 is KSPickButton {  
      $0.removeFromSuperview() 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Note that using tags to find views is fragile. Saving your buttons to an array is a much better idea.